# Is it possible to json_decode a json data with base64 encoded data in it?

Tags: php, json, base64

I have a json data looks like the below fig.

Notice the "img" key holds a base64 data.

Im using php to do this.

[image]

Comment: Yes as long as it is a valid JSON String

Comment: Put the actual json string ( or a valid real example of one ) somewhere we can play with it please. Repeating the question without adding any more information will not get you an answer

Comment: You probably already tried it, did it error?

Comment: Please DONT post images. They are NO USE to us if we want to work out what is wrong with the data

Comment: `json_decode` and then `base64_decode` that element?

Comment: @AbraCadaver We got to that in the previous incarnation of this question. Prev question got us to the fact that the JSON String will not decode because there is an errror in it but cannot get access to a decent example that is not a picture. So we are dancing round and getting knowhere

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is totally possible to decode the json data containing `base64_encoded` data as long as it is a valid json format.You can always use `json_decode` to decode the data or `base64_encoded` string received from the server.

Comment: Really, this is useful because the comments are invisible?